# send file upload to dropbox

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, upload, dropbox

I want to send the uploads via javaScript to the drop box. All the referring posts at stackoverflow link to not existant pages.

I'm using a NOde.js server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as AJAX from server -> server. It's really just HTTP requests or however dropbox API works.

This module should help you, first hit on google "node.js dropbox"

https://github.com/sintaxi/node-dbox